# Avoiding duplicate entity mappings with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 2.1.0 and multiple DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I've just started working on an existing codebase. It's an AngularJS frontend with a WebAPI backend. It's currently using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.1.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 2.1.0 with code first EntityFramework 6.1.1

The problem I'm having is that the codebase currently uses two database contexts, and these contexts both map to a single underlying table.

The first dbcontext is used **only** to support ASP.Net Identity;

```
public class AccountSecurityDBContext : IdentityDbContext<AccountUser, AccountRole, Guid, AccountUserLogin, AccountUserRole, AccountUserClaim>
{
   ...
   modelBuilder.Entity<AccountUser>().ToTable("User");
   ...
}
```

where AccountUser **must** derive from IdentityUser due to ASP.Net Identity.requirements;

```
public class AccountUser : IdentityUser<Guid, AccountUserLogin, AccountUserRole, AccountUserClaim>
{
   ...
}
```

This AccountUser class is purely used to satisfy ASP.Net Identity. The the second DbContext has another mapping to the User table, used for everything other than authentication.

```
public class MainContextUnitOfWork : DbContext
{
   ...
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
   ...
}
```

So, currently, there are two classes, AccountUser and User both mapping to the same underlying User  table.

This use of two DbContexts each with their own mapping to the same underlying table is causing problems. EntityFramework wants to create two migrations, one per DbContext resulting in the generation of duplicate migrations. I am aware of the add-migration --ignore option so that we can generate an empty migration for the second DbContext and that empty migration will generate a new hash of the data model in the empty migrations's designer.cs file.

Ideally I feel we should really only be using one DbContext as it's rather confusing having two DbContexts where we're using one of the DbContexts purely to support ASP.Net Identity. However I can't see how to easily refactor due to the fact that to use ASP.Net Identity the user entity **must** derive from IdentityUser. It's not acceptable for us to have an Entity deriving from IdentityUser to be passed up to higher layers in the appplication as this would introduce a dependency on EntityFramework in those higher layers.

My current feeling is that use of ASP.Net Identity is causing more problems than it's solving and that we'd be better off implementing our own authentication mechanism.

To reiterate. The problem lies in the fact that ASP.Net Identity forces inheritance from IdentityUser rather than allowing, for example, an implementation based on a (non-existent) IIdentityUser interface.

I've been unable to find any examples of how to overcome this.

So, the question is; Has anyone successfully used ASP.Net Identity 2.1.0 with EntityFramework 6.1.1 where you've been able to both accommodate the ASP.Net Identity requirements of using a class derived from IdentityUser and to pass a User entity up to application layers without having to reference EntityFramework in those higher layers.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple. Although we are using EntityFramework and Asp.Net Identity, we didn't actually want to use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.

What we needed to do was just use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and implement our own user and role store.